# equivalent of cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap() for uncalibrated cameras

Tags: opencv

after calculating H1 and H2 using  cv2.stereoRectifyUncalibrated()
Now, I would like to create my rectification-maps. I know that in the calibrated case I could use cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap()
 is their any equivalent for uncalibrated cameras?

Comment: you want to use the same H1 and H2 for all frames and want to speedup the transformation by using remap? Or do you just want to apply the transformations?

Comment: I just want to apply the transformations to build the rectified images rectify1 and rectify2  for the uncalibrated case

Comment: warpPerspective function

Comment: thanks for the hint, this actually lead me to the next question which is how can we build the mapx and mapy for remapping for uncalibrated cases. in other words is there equivalent for cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap for uncalibrated cameras.

Comment: you can use the homography on each pixel position and save the result to mapx and mapy manually. Afaik there is jo builtin function, but maybe google has an answer.